# View coordinate in Screen

Tags: android, view

I have the next question:

Im developing an app that when i move a imageView and drop it, if the view drops under the half height of the screen goes to a (X,Y) position and if is over the half height  screen, goes to another position.

I need to calculate the half of the screen generic, so i use the next code:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
halfHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels / 2;
```

This works great, im trying in a screen 1920x1080, the code returns 540. 
But when im going to see if when i drop the view is under or over the half, here is what i dont understand. i get the Y position of the view and is ok, what i dont understand is why the Y = 0 is not on the TOP of the screen, if i move the view to the top, i get a negative Y position like -260.

Someone can explain me why this happen?
Is there i way that the (0,0) position starts in the top left of the screen?

Greets, hope you understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call getX() or getY() then you are getting relative values for x and y (relative to the view that the call was dispatched from).  If you call [getRawX()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getRawX()) or [getRawY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getRawY()) it will give you the absolute position of the view relative to the device's screen.

Most likely you are getting negative values of -260 because you are dragging the ImageView 260 away from the view in which the call was made (perhaps the view on the top of the screen has a height of 260).  If you are trying to use getX() or getY() to calculate the middle of the screen then you would have to take all sizes of all views into consideration but I think you want to use [getRawX()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getRawX()) and [getRawY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getRawY())

Comment: Thanks that help me. So if a call view.getX() its going to return the x, y position, starting from the coordinates view position to the moment i drop it? calculates that distance?

Answer (score 0):

An angle of 0 degrees correspond to the geometric angle of 0 degrees (3 o'clock on a watch.)

try using translate to translate the co-ordinates to top of the screen.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#translate(float, float)